# TemplateDoesNotExist at /edit-narration/13/edit/

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Why is my narrate_update_form template not showing? And why am I getting

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /narration/7/edit/

narrate_update_form
```

My views.py is:

```
class NarrateUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Narrate
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'narrate_update_form'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['narrate'] = Narrate.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

On my narrate template I have this button:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit-narration' narrate.pk %}" value="Update">Edit/Update</a>
```

On the narrate_update_form.html, I have:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be `template_name = 'narrate_update_form.html'`, you need to add `html` there.

Also depending on where the template file actually is, you might need to specify a relative path to it.